# Debugging tool for Chrome Extension notification window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I created a notification window using the Chrome Extension API:

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification("notification.html");
notification.show();
```

Also there is an external notification.js for all the scripts I would like to run in the notification window (Since the [manifest version 2](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html) discourages inline javascript). Everything works fine except I couldn't open developer tools for the notification window to inspect the page. I can do it for the background as well as the popup pages, so not sure if I didn't find it or I simply can't inspect notification through the developer tool. I know I can send messages between background and notification so that outputs show up on the console, but it would be nice if I could inspect directly.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigate to `chrome://inspect/` and you can see all the pages that can be inspected. Under the section "Extensions" you should be able to see your notification page and you can inspect it.

Adding this answer for completeness, because @JJin's answer *may* had been working before but not in Chrome versions 24 and 25.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I accidently found that the developer tool is available for the notification page. The trick is to

- fire up the notification window first and keep it on;
- navigate to `chrome://extensions` and `notification.html` should appear alongside the `background.html` or whatever name the background page's name is,
  as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Make sure the notification window is on otherwise the `notification.html` would disappear.

Comment: did you do anything in you manifest file? I still can't see my notification html.

Comment: Yes, you need to add permission for notifications.

Comment: I do not see the notification window listed in 'Inspect views' (I do have notification permissions). Is there something you need do to get it displayed (am on version 24.0.1312.57)?

Comment: @source.rar I added another answer which should be able to help you.

Comment: @Alvin Wong: Thanks that works. OP pls consider making Alvin's response as the correct answer.